# How to open file based on HTML form entries

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have two separate fields with a drop-down list, one is for User and the second Data. Then I have a button, which would ideally work as an output of the selection of the two drop-down lists. The form should retrieve the file that is relevant to the selection. The file to be opened has always the following format so I was hoping to make use of that: _.csv

Here's the simplified version of what I'm using:

```
<td align="left"><!-- User/data selector -->
  <table border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th align="left">User:</th>
        <td>
        <select name="users" id="users">
        <option value="user1">User 1</option>
        <option value="user2">User 2</option>
        <option value="user3">User 3</option>
        </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th align="left">Data:</th>
        <td>
        <select name="data" id="data">
        <option value="data1">Data 1</option>
        <option value="data2">Data 2</option>
        <option value="data3">Data 3</option>                    
        </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type='button' value='Generate Report' onClick='newWindow();'/></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

So, what I'm struggling with is to know what to write in the function `newWindow()` to get the needed 'User' and 'Data' selection to get the correct file. Can you help?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Please remember to also accept the answers that solved your previous questions, if there has been such an answer.

Comment: It worked, I didn't come back to my question until today. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the values of those `<select>` fields with `document.getElementById(id).value`, where `id` would be `data` or `users`, in order to make up the csv file name.

The `openWindow` function could look like:

```
function openWindow(){
    var users = document.getElementById('users').value;
    var data = document.getElementById('data').value
    var fileName =  users + "_" + data + ".csv";
    var pathToFiles = "/whateverdirectory/";

    window.open(pathToFiles + fileName, fileName);
}
```

Also, remember you [shouldn't be using `<table>`s for layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/83073/851811), they're meant for displaying tabular data. It is recommended to use `<div>`s instead.

You might also find this blog entry useful: [Using the window.open method](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml).